# Discord.js Setting slash commands as private

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm using djs v14 and I want to set certain slash commands as "private" for example my bot is in 10 servers, I want only one of these servers to be able to view a certain category of slash commands but the other slash commands would be global as normal

I searched through Discord js's Guide and couldn't find answers for my questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For specific guild slash command you can just using : https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/GuildApplicationCommandManager?scrollTo=set

```js
await guildData.commands.set(slashBuilderInformation);
```